# 1-D Graph in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to reproduce the solid blue graph on the left hand side in the following picture:

[image]

The analytical expression for the graph is:

> $$ - \frac{1}{\tau} \ln \Bigg ( \Bigg [ \frac{|\eta|}{1 + |\eta|^2} \Bigg ]^{4J} \sum_{m, p = -1}^{1} |\eta|^{2(m + p)}   \binom{2J}{J + m} \binom{2J}{J + p} e^{- i \triangle(\tau)(m^2 - p^2)} e^{\gamma(\tau)(m - p)^2} \Bigg ). $$

My code is:

```
G = 0.01;
β = 1;
ωc = 50;
J = 1;
ϕ = 0;
θ = π/2;


integralgamma[ω_, τ_] := 
 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - 
   Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2];


integraldelta[ω_, τ_] := 
  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[ω τ] - \
 ω τ)/ω^2;

Plot[- (1/τ)
 Log [(Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2) )^(4 J) * 
  Sum[Binomial[2 J, J + m] * Binomial[2 J, J + p] * 
   Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) * 
    Exp[-NIntegrate[
     integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 70000}, 
      Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
       MaxRecursion -> 15]* (m - p)^2] * 
        Exp[- I * 
         NIntegrate[
          integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 70000}, 
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
            MaxRecursion -> 15]* (m^2 - p^2)]  , {m, -1, 1, 1}, {p, -1, 
             1, 1}]], {τ, 0, 2}]
```

But I get an empty graph:

[image]

Help please.

**P.S:** Here's the analytical expression from the paper:

[image]

$\eta = e^{i \phi} \tan \Bigg (\frac{\theta}{2} \Bigg )$. In my case, $\eta$ stands for the weird symbol that appears in $|...|$ in the paper.

Comment: Something is going wrong with your brackets in the code as posted.

Comment: @Feyre Can you help pin point the error? :/

Comment: For one, you are missing a closing bracket, presumably before `, {\[Tau], 0, 2}` You should use `I` capital i for the imaginary unit. It would appear your `Sum[]`s are cancelling to 0.

Comment: @Feyre The sums shouldn't be cancelling to zero. I'm trying to reproduced a graph which gives a non-trivial plot. Any errors with the code?

Comment: @Feyre A few tweaks reduce the numbers of errors I'm getting. See the edit.

Comment: There appears to be an error in your formula somewhere, I'm not getting any errors, but tau reaches `ComplexInfinity` at `0`.

Comment: @Feyre What do you mean the last part, tau approaches what? Also, if you're not getting any error with the same code, what could be going wrong?

Comment: What is $n$ in the analytical expression?

Comment: @Young That's just a typo. Replace the n with a p throughout. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Should there be an imaginary symbol in the gamma exponential function or not?

Comment: @Young Again, typo. Apologies. Edited.

Comment: That means that the limit approaches $\pm \infty$

Comment: @Feyre and others: I have re-edited/tweaked my code to better conform it with the details on the paper. Previously, I had made some algebraic simplifications on my own. Have a look at the edited post.

Comment: I still get the same, the code works fine, as long as you start `tau` at `0.1` And the form is still not what you posted in the image. It does have some resemblance, peaking around `1.5` for example.

Comment: @Feyre I further reedited the post. Can you find any discrepancy between the stuff copies from the paper and the code and its out? I think my expressions for $\gamma(\tau)$ etc. are correct as well, although I will triple check them. Any potential errors with the code that is giving the wrong graph before $\tau = 1.6$?

Comment: The current code seems to run perfectly, are you still getting errors?

Comment: It runs perfectly now. Thanks guys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42796/discussion-between-junaid-aftab-and-feyre).

Comment: @JunaidAftab I'm curious, what paper is this from?

Comment: @Young See the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

After reviewing the referenced [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.5228v1.pdf), *Zeno and anti-Zeno effects on Dephasing*, I discovered that the summation range should be {-$J,J$} for both $m$ and $p$. The graph now shows $J=1$ and $J=2$ as depicted in the paper.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G = 1/100;
β = 1;
ωc = 50;
ϕ = 0;
θ = π/2;

η = Exp[I ϕ] Tan[θ/2];

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] :=  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2]

integraldelta[ω_, τ_] :=  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[ω τ] - ω τ)/ω^2

δ[τ_] :=  NIntegrate[integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 10000}, 
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 10]
γ[τ_] :=  NIntegrate[integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 10000},
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 10]

f[τ_] := -(1/τ) Log[
      (Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2))^(4 j) 
      Sum[Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) Binomial[2 j, j + m] Binomial[2 j,  j + p] 
      Exp[-I δ[τ] (m^2 - p^2)] Exp[-γ[τ] (m - p)^2 ], 
      {m, -j, j, 1}, {p, -j, j, 1}]]

Plot[{f[τ] /. j -> 1, f[τ] /. j -> 2}, {τ, 0.01, 2.01},
 PlotRange -> {0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Purple, Dashed]}]
```

[image]

---

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G = 0.01;
β = 1;
j = 1;
ωc = 50;
ϕ = 0;
θ = π/2;

η = Exp[I ϕ] Tan[θ/2];

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] :=  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2]

integraldelta[ω_, τ_] :=  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[ω τ] - ω τ)/ω^2

δ[τ_] :=  NIntegrate[integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 10000}, 
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15]
γ[τ_] :=  NIntegrate[integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 10000},
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15]

f[τ_] := -(1/τ) Log[
      (Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2))^(4 j) 
      Sum[Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) Binomial[2 j, j + m] Binomial[2 j,  j + p] 
      Exp[-I δ[τ] (m^2 - p^2)] Exp[-γ[τ] (m - p)^2 ], 
      {m, -1, 1, 1}, {p, -1, 1, 1}]]

Plot[f[τ], {τ, 0.01, 2.01}, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 0]
```

Comment: Please check my last comment in the comments above.

Comment: Your code gives me the error `Set::write: Tag Times in f \[Tau]_ is Protected. >>`. What could it mean?

Comment: @JunaidAftab You need to clear your variables or restart the kernel

Comment: Yep, figured it out. Yeah, I'll upvote and accept it. Do the same if you think the question was worth the hassle. Thanks.

Comment: As an option? `Plot[..., {PlotPoints->100}]`?

Comment: By the way, I'm still getting an empty plot using your code. You define additional functions for gamma and tau and don't run nested commands? What could be the issue?

Comment: After I run the code, I get an empty plot. No error but the graph shows nothing. What could be the issue?

Comment: I get the most bizarre graph. Probably, I am doing something wrong. I'm taking this to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42787/discussion-between-junaid-aftab-and-young).

Comment: See the chat, Young.